# converting Date and Seconds

Tags: php, datetime, strtotime

While using `strtotime` function , if i am giving `+48 day` i am not sure whether is working fine or not ?

```
 <?php
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
$Seconds = 8604800 ;
$At = "2018-11-28 12:16:19";    
echo  date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime("+48 day",strtotime($tAt)));

?>
```

Comment: "+7 day" is relative to the current time. If you compute a number of seconds, you need to tell the system "that many seconds from now". As it is written, you're telling the system "that many seconds", which will probably be interpreted as "after Jan 1st, 1970".

Comment: You asked something similar yesterday - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53476272/here-i-want-to-7-days-into-seconds-i-written-the-code-but-not-working-properly and as pointed out last week and the week before!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Here i want to +7 days into seconds,i written the code but not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53476272/here-i-want-to-7-days-into-seconds-i-written-the-code-but-not-working-properly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strtotime` expects the first parameter to be a valid time string. You are providing the number of seconds. Try -

```
echo $requestValidTill = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime("+$resetPasswordDurationInSeconds SECONDS",strtotime($requestAt)));
```

**Output**

```
2018-12-05 12:16:19
```

[strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

[Working code](https://eval.in/1062725)

Comment: Working perfectly for me. Must have done something wrong. Check the working code link.

Answer (score 0):

if you have PHP 5.3+ you can use the following lines of code

```
$requestAt  = "2018-11-28 12:16:19";
$resetPasswordDurationInSeconds = 604800 ; //60 * 60 * 24 * 7  ( +7 days in seconds )
$date = new DateTime($requestAt );
$date->add(new DateInterval('PT'.$resetPasswordDurationInSeconds.'S')); // adds 604800 secs
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $date->getTimestamp());
```

Answer (score 0):

Your just need to add seconds in `strtotime`

```
<?php
$requestAt  = strtotime("2018-11-28 12:16:19");
$requestAt += 604800;
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $requestAt);
?>
```

[Live Demo](https://eval.in/1062729)